# MAUI Binding, how to put RelayCommand in ViewModel instead of Model and pass Model data as a parameter?

Tags: .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

How do I bind a [RelayCommand] "PlayVideoCommand" to have data from the model "VideoID" but the command is in the viewmodel? As it stands it wants me to put the command in the model itself but that doesn't make sense to me.

```
<CollectionView
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Margin="0,0"
            RemainingItemsThreshold="5"
            RemainingItemsThresholdReached="OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached"
            ItemsSource="{Binding YourVideos}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Video">
                    <Grid
                        Margin="0,0"
                        Padding="20">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                               Margin="10,0"
                               Source="{Binding LocalThumbnail}"
                               Aspect="AspectFill"
                               HeightRequest="60"
                               WidthRequest="60">

                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer
                                    Command="{Binding PlayVideoCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding VideoID, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                               Text="{Binding Title}"
                               FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label 
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Text="{Binding Subtitle}"
                               FontAttributes="Italic"
                               VerticalOptions="End" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Comment: It looks like it might but i'm getting this error now and I can't figure out what I need to add to get it to resolve "The property 'RelativeSource' was not found in type 'BindingExtension'"

Comment: what is the exact binding expression you are using?

Comment: Command="{Binding Path=VideoID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListVideosView}}}"

Comment: you have `RelativeSource` twice.  See the final comment on the linked question where they provide the correct syntax.  Or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings

Comment: Thanks I imagine that is the fix. I copied that bad syntax from the linked answer you provided earlier. Keep being awesome Jason.

Comment: If you truly have your RelayCommand inside your ViewModel, you shouldn't need a CommandParameter. The reason is, your RelayCommand has access to everything in the ViewModel instance.